# Ставятся ли кавычки в сочетании прямая линия?

Tags: кавычки

**Президент провел прямую линию**.
**Состоится прямая линия**.
**В ходе прямой линии**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос № 237863
Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли брать в кавычки выражения горячий телефон, прямая линия, круглый стол?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Кавычки не нужны.

ПРЯМАЯ ЛИНИЯ

1. геометр. линия, на которой расстояние между любыми двумя точками является кратчайшим
2. ряд ближайших родственников, соединённых кровной связью
3. телефонная или иная линия связи, предназначенная для организованного общения граждан с компетентными лицами
   Источник:
   [https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/прямая+линия](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)